# How to have a MSI package to change installed Win32 application compatibility options

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-7, windows-installer, windows-server-2008

Our Win32 applications need to write in their installation directory. So under Windows 7 and Server 2008, this requires administrator rights.
Currently we manually check the "run as administrator" option in the properties/compatibility tab of the EXE file.
Is there a way to do this automatically during the installation of the MSI?

Comment: This is [not the answer you want](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/11/9976571.aspx "Raymond Chen on automatically setting compatibility options"), but one you should probably consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a manifest file to your application to make it ask for elevation at startup is a better workaround.

Comment: Can I add a manifest file to a Win32 application (not .NET x86, but Win32 Delphi or C++) ?

Comment: Of course you can. The simplest way is to add a <yourexe>.exe.manifest file there.

Comment: The easiest way I found to do it is to use the "MT.EXE" tool provided by Microsoft. See Method #2 of this blog post: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/cheller/archive/2006/08/24/718757.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: @20c maybe make another answer from it?